# How to set default method when creating a new custom class?

Tags: ios, class, methods, uiviewcontroller, viewdidload

I have created `ABViewController` (inherited from `UIViewController`). It has default methods when created (**initWithNibName** , **viewDidLoad** , **didReceiveMemoryWarning**).
So, I wanna set more default method in my custom class such as **"setInterface,setData"**.

Comment: you mean you want new template for create new class?

Comment: Yes, Have any suggest? ><

Comment: you can either google for xcode template or use code snippet manager tool

Comment: Thank you very much. I found the solution, but it's be config IDE level, i just need custom class file template only one project. It's not the good solution. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one trick:

Write required method definition and call it inside `viewDidLoad`.

It's just a trick.